# error in validating the bool condition

Tags: c#

i have added a usercontrol on a panel and set the property of combobox which is in usercontrol to public, i want to validate that but all the time i click the button it shows the form. whats the problem, how to validate when i have added multiple combobox dynamically by a button.

```
bool tat;
public bool val2()
{
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    {
        if (item.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            tat = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tat = false;
        }
    }

    return tat;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool valo = val2();

    if (!valo)
    {
        Form4 fp = new Form4();
        fp.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add the `ComboBox` dynamically, is the `text` property populated?

Comment: yess ofcourse if combobox is added to a usercontrol and set to public then it will have text property.

Comment: Then you will never get the `text` value to be empty there for it will always return `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is *overwriting* the value of `tat` each time through your loop, e.g.:

```
ComboBox1    "Hello"   tat = false
ComboBox2    Empty     tat = true
ComboBox3    "World"   tat = false again!
             Return:   false
```

I assume you want to return true if *any* combo box is empty; you can modify your function as follows:

```
public bool val2()
{
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    {
        if (item.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            // We know one is empty so we must return true.
            return true;
        }
    }
    // We know none are empty so we can return false.
    return false;
}
```

Or since you're already using LINQ, you could use

```
public bool val2()
{
    return panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
}
```

which will do the exact same thing.

---

Edit: It *also* looks like your `ComboBox` controls aren't *direct* children of `panel1`, but are inside some sort of custom user control. Thus you'll need something like

```
return panel1.Controls
    .OfType<YourCustomUserControlType>()
    .Select(uc => uc.NameOfYourComboBox)
    .Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
```

So the `OfType` line is now picking out your custom user controls, the `Select` line takes one of your user controls and finds the `ComboBox`, and the `Any` line checks if they all have values.

Alternative in original style:

```
public bool val2()
{
    foreach (YourCustomUserControlType item in 
        panel1.Controls.OfType<YourCustomUserControlType>())
    {
        ComboBox cb = item.NameOfYourComboBox;
        if (cb.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            // We know one is empty so we must return true.
            return true;
        }
    }
    // We know none are empty so we can return false.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: your solution is also opening the form when the button is click,
means it is not working properly,
        int c = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int v;
            v = c++;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;


            UserControl1 us = new UserControl1();
            us.Name = "us" + v;
            us.Location = new Point(150, 5 + (30 * v));
            
            panel1.Controls.Add(us);
           
        }
i added the user control by this code,is this posible to validate by your code?

Comment: Aaah wait. `panel1.Controls` will return _immediate_ children of your panel, but it looks like your dropdowns are further in. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sir,it is working properly, but how do you know i am using linq?

Comment: `OfType` is a LINQ method. I can update my non-LINQ code too if that would help.

Comment: thank you sir, really, and previously i used
 Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12}$");
            if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
this type of regex. can i implement regex in your code?
is that possible?

Comment: Yup; just define `regex` somewhere accessible (e.g. at the start of `val2()` and replace `cb.Text == String.Empty` with `!regex.IsMatch(cb.Text)`.

Comment: sir, i replaces it with
!regex.IsMatch(cb.Text) and declared this  
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-z]$");
and used this code for button click event
           
            bool val21 = val3();
            if (!val21)
            {
                Form4 fp = new Form4();
                fp.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");

            }
but it error all the time even if it is blank or it is filled with upper and lower case it errors

Comment: That regex only allows one character; you need `^[a-z]+$` - or your original regex with the `{4,12}` in it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're deciding the value of `val2` for every combo box. Probably, the last combo box has a value, so the form is shown instead of the message box.. If you want the result to be `true` only if *all* combo boxes have selected values, you need to go for a solution like the following:

Assume that all combo boxes have selected values. As soon as only *one*  doesn't have a value, return `true`;

```
public bool val2()
{
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool valo = val2();

    if (!valo)
    {
        Form4 fp = new Form4();
        fp.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");

    }
}
```